# How can I convert a sparql query result into a string array?

Tags: java, sparql, jena

This is the code that I have and it returns only the first row, I need to be able to handle all the rows as a String. How could I put the output of ResultSetFormatter.out(ps, results, query) into an array of strings?

```
//convert sparql query results into string array
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
ResultSetFormatter.out(ps, results, query);
String queryOutput = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");

System.out.println(queryOutput);
```

Comment: If you can get a string for one row, can't you just repeat it in a loop and collect all the rows?

Comment: Also, SPARQL is just a query language, and doesn't define anything like ResultSetFormatter, or even Arrays.  This is a Jena specific question and you'll benefit from getting Jena-specific eyes on it, as well as Java-specific eyes.  I've added [tag:jena] and [tag:java] tags.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided *should* output the entire `results` object as an ascii table within `ps`. If you are only seeing one row, then it is because your query is returning only one row, or because you need to flush the `PrintStream`

To validate that you are getting only one row, wrap the results and print them (pseudocode):

```
final ResultSetRewindable r = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results);
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, r, query);
r.reset();
ResultSetFormatter.out(ps, r, query); // Continue as you were
```

If you should be getting more than one row (as observed by running the previous code), add a call to flush `ps` prior to converting it to a string:

```
ps.flush();
String queryOutput = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Note that `ps` should contain everything that was written to `System.out`, so if you are not seeing those values when you convert `baos`, then it's likely that `ps` hadn't transferred those values to the underlying stream. `flush` will force that transfer to occur.

Also, you may not need `ps` at all, because `ResultSetFormatter.out` only needs an `OutputStream`. For example, you can just write directly to `baos`.

Comment: It worked with the code provided above, I also notice that you have to call the function ResultSetFormatter only once (at least not before you do all the necessary code to convert the query into a String), Thanks.

Comment: Good catch! It's also important to note that unless you have a `ResultSetRewindable`, the `ResultSet` is a one-pass iterator. If you found this answer satisfactory in helping you to solve your problem, you may wish to consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).